# Python deque performance for small iterables

Tags: python, performance, deque

I was playing around with Python's collection.deque and wrote the following benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import timeit

if __name__=='__main__':
    number = 1000000
    for r in (1,10,100,1000,5000,10000,100000):
        print r
        print timeit.timeit("while x: x.pop(0);",
                            "x = list(range("+str(r)+"))",
                            number=number)
        print timeit.timeit("while x: x.popleft();",
                            "from collections import deque; x = deque(range("+str(r)+"))",
                             number=number)
```

This will pop(0)/popleft() from a list/deque with various sizes. The results are:

```
1
0.0801048278809
0.0822219848633
10
0.081041097641
0.080836057663
100
0.0806250572205
0.0807700157166
1000
0.081248998642
0.082062959671
5000
0.0976719856262
0.0825741291046
10000
0.157499074936
0.0825819969177
100000
16.0247170925
0.097559928894
```

My question is: Why is the performance for small deques and lists (~1000 elements) almost the same?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that `import` statements are not free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timeit module runs the setup code once, and then the timed code `number` times (in this case, `number`==1000000). In your case this looks like (for the list case):

```
x = list(range(r))
#timer is started here
for iteration in xrange(1000000):
    while x: x.pop(0)
#timer is stopped here
```

As you can see, only the first iteration does anything, and the other 999999 iterations will just check the size of `x` once since it will be empty. This check will take approximately the same amount of time for lists and deques.

For small lists/deques, the first iteration is short relative to the other 999999 iterations combined, so you are not really measuring anything relevant, and get similar times.

If you use `number==1` you won't have this problem. Another option is to have the timed code push and pop an item so that the list/deque is left at the same size.

Answer (score 3):

I always find `timeit` more suitable for use from the shell command line. Here, for example:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'from collections import deque; base=range(100); ctr=list' 'x=ctr(base)' 'while x: x.pop(0)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.3 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'from collections import deque; base=range(100); ctr=deque' 'x=ctr(base)' 'while x: x.popleft()'
10000 loops, best of 3: 36 usec per loop
```

The needed precautions (doing the import outside the loop, making a fresh copy of the data within the loop) are so much easier to see and implement, this way...

Answer (score 2):

<strike>For low numbers of elements, the time taken to construct the deque and list is significant.</strike>

Once the number f elements grows, this it's no longer significant in the results.

Rewrite the test so that construction of lists is outside of the timeit call.

Edit: As @Interjar points out, the initialization of classes is done outside of the method timing so this is not the reason for the similar timings on low numbers of entries.

Comment: This is incorrect: the list construction is done in the `setup` paremeter to `timeit`, which isn't timed.